# What holds the overhead lockers?

Tags: aircraft-design

If they carry a lot of weight inside, what avoids them from falling down to the passenger's heads? What holds them? How are they mounted inside the cabin?

Comment: Screws into structural frames

Comment: Are you asking about the design structure of how the overhead lockers are mounted in the aircraft? Or are you asking about the latching mechanism for the overhead lockers?

Comment: @JonathanWalters I'm asking  about how they are mounted in the aircraft

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The overhead bins are usually mounted to the aircraft structure. For example, in case of Boeing 737, they are mounted to the stingers using tie rods. From an [accident report of Boeing 737-400](http://www.rvs.uni-bielefeld.de/publications/Incidents/DOCS/ComAndRep/Kegworth/AAIB/COPY/gobmerep.htm):

> The forward inertial load is reacted by a diagonal tie, mounted at one end to stringer 6 or 7 in the fuselage crown and at the other end to a fitting on the upper surface of the bin. The vertical and lateral loads are reacted by short tie rods attached to the fuselage.

[image: 737 overhead bin]

B737-400 overhead bin attachment. Image from the [same report](http://www.rvs.uni-bielefeld.de/publications/Incidents/DOCS/ComAndRep/Kegworth/AAIB/COPY/gobmerep.htm).